# HQL count distinct lower syntax

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I want to lowercase all users usernames, then count how many distinct ones there are, but getting an error on this hql query:

```
select count(distinct lower(user.username)) from UserEntity as user

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'user' near line 1, column 29 [select count(distinct lower(user.username))
```

This works fine:

```
select count(distinct user.username) from UserEntity as user
```

But when I add the lower(...) it it fails, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How do you send that query to hibernate ? As it is formatted as a native SQL query, you could try to use createSQLQuery ...

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Serge Ballesta, I ended up just running this as a SQL query instead of a HQL query, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

`select count(lower(user.username)) from UserEntity as user group by lower(user.username)`?

My guess is that you are messing with aggregate functions and statements: `count(disctinct lower(...))` is a [aggregated function] - [statement] - [aggregated function] pattern which HQL doesn't support (or at least [doesn't treat in documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation)).